# How to compare hundreds of one-dimensional functions

Tags: distance-functions, function

I have hundreds (2002 in today's case) of functions of the distance between two objects: $f_1(x)$, $f_2(x)$, ..., $f_{2002}(x)$. They are correlation functions. They all converge to 0 when $x$ is large enough.

They are extracted by histogram methods from numerical simulations, so I have couples of values $\{x_i, f_1(x_i)\}$ where typically $i$ can take 1024 discrete values. The $x_i$ are the same for all functions. $x$ is a distance so it's between 0 and say 100.

To make it clear, I have a huge table that looks like:

$x_1$; $f_1(x_1)$; $f_2(x_1)$; ...; $f_{2002}(x_1)$
$x_2$; $f_1(x_2)$; $f_2(x_2)$; ...; $f_{2002}(x_2)$
$x_3$; $f_1(x_3)$; $f_2(x_3)$; ...; $f_{2002}(x_3)$
...

Are there methods to compare the functions $f$ rigorously? Or at least to get a better insight that just plotting them and trying to see something?

Note: In today's case, these functions can have Imaginary part, that is, they can be Complex numbers but an answer for real functions would be extremely helpful.

Thanks for reading my question ! :)

edit: I'm not looking for a way to quantify the whole dataset, for instance the most "important" functions, those similar, those smaller ...

Comment: What do you want to learn about them? What does "important" mean to you?  For instance, is a function with low correlation to others interesting?  Or are you interested in finding groups of highly correlated functions (e.g. clustering).  Either way, you can turn stack the vectors of functions to create a matrix `M` and do any kind of matrix decomposition or unsupervised learning on `M`.

Comment: I do not know exactly: I have those correlation functions and would like to extract some physical interpretation or something to learn at least out of them. I could use them without any interpretation but for sure something is embedded there. Low correlations are indeed less important, but highly localized correlations could make the integral of one of the functions quite small relative to the other but nevertheless interesting. Could you please point something to the method you propose ?

Answer (score 1):

This perhaps should be a function for maths SE (I've voted to close it as belonging there in fact), but if you assume the functions are *defined* by the values you have and some interpolation between them, so for instance

$$f_1(x) = \begin{cases}
 f_1(x_1) + \frac{(x - x_1)\left(f_1(x_2) - f_1(x_1)\right)}{x_2 - x_1} &x\in [x_1,x_2)\\
 \cdots\\
 f_1(x_{n-1}) + \frac{(x - x_{n-1})\left(f_1(x_n) - f_1(x_{n-1})\right)}{x_n - x_{n-1}} & x\in [x_{n-1},x_n]
\end{cases}
$$

& so on.

(Note $f_i(x)$ defined like this is not everywhere differentiable, but that's fine: wer're not going to differentiate it.)
Then you can treat them as vectors in a function space with inner product

$$\langle f_i, f_j\rangle = \int\limits_{x_1}^{x_n} \overline{f_i(x)} f_j(x)\,dx$$

This gives you a distance measure between $f_i$ & $f_j$ as $\langle f_i - f_j, f_i - f_j\rangle$.

Look up functional analysis, Hilbert spaces and specifically $L^p$ spaces (I think the space you care about is $L^2$ -- the space of square-integrable functions.